# Split a number in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called "Site" with value as following:

```
Clj2
Cob
Cob2
Abt 234
Abt4
Bani
```

I would like to take only the alpha chars into a new column "Sitename" without numbers or spaces which means the result should be like this:

```
Clj
Cob
Cob
Abt
Abt
Bani
```

Below is the code that I checked...

**Code 1**:

```
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%0%' 
THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%0%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%1%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%1%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%2%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%2%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%3%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%3%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%4%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%4%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%5%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%5%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%6%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%6%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%7%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%7%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%8%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%8%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN TableUser.[site] LIKE '%9%' THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('%9%',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(TableUser.[site])) >0 THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX(' ',TableUser.[site],0))
ELSE TableUser.[site]
END as [sitename]
```

**Code 2**:

```
CASE
WHEN CHARINDEX('[0-9]',(TableUser.[site])) >0 THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX('[0-9]',TableUser.[site],0))
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(TableUser.[site])) >0 THEN Substring(TableUser.[site],0, CHARINDEX(' ',TableUser.[site],0))
ELSE TableUser.[site]
END as [sitename]
```

**'[0-9]' also tried with %[0-9]% or %[^0-9]% or [[:digit:]]

It works with the ' ' part (`Abt 234` --> `Abt`) this OK,
but not with the number (`Cob2` is still shown as `Cob2`)

Can anyone help me out?
Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: Have you tried the `REPLACE` function?

Comment: Hello Dale K, sorry I am just learning SQL, still very amateur :) How the REPLACE work? Can you please suggest? Thank you.

Comment: Please read the documentation... thats a good way to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with a regex that will match everything except the first characters like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', site) = 0 
            THEN site
            ELSE SUBSTRING(site, 1, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', site)-1)
       END
FROM TableUser
```

If there's no other character than char in the string, it'll return the string as is, otherwise it truncates the string at the first instance of different char.

Pattern `%[^A-Za-z]%`: matches the first occurrence of any non-alphabetical character.

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d40a6ac3bc30f06657453e8e47d099be).

Answer (score 2):

you can use [translate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Returns the string provided as a first argument after some characters
> specified in the second argument are translated into a destination set
> of characters specified in the third argument.

```
trim(translate(site, '0123456789', '          '))
```

[`trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is to remove any space at the start or end of the string after translate